# How to find out if speaker burned out?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, speakers

Last night I was listening to music over headphones when my laptop shutdown out of the blue... I turn it back on and realize the speakers don't work anymore, this is what I try already:
Kill pulse audio in all different ways from old post on ask Ubuntu, unistall alsa and purge everything to reinstall and restart and nothing.. The headphones audio work well,Bluetoth audio works well, its the speakers that stop working out of the blue.

Here is the `pacmd list-sinks` output:

```
2 sink(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 9050
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 39,08 ms
    max request: 6 KiB
    max rewind: 64 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 40,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 371,52 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
    module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "HDMI 0"
        alsa.id = "HDMI 0"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "3"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xd3000000 irq 17"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0be3"
        device.product.name = "High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.string = "hdmi:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        device.description = "High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Nvidia GPU 0b HDMI/DP"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10de000b,10de0101,00100200"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
    active port: <hdmi-output-0>
  * index: 2
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-surround-40>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 9959
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   rear-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   rear-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 39,93 ms
    max request: 13 KiB
    max rewind: 64 KiB
    monitor source: 2
    sample spec: s16le 4ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right
                 Surround 4.0
    used by: 0
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 40,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 185,76 ms
    card: 1 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "92HD75B3X5 Analog"
        alsa.id = "92HD75B3X5 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel MID"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel MID at 0xd7420000 irq 32"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1b.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "3b56"
        device.product.name = "5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "surround40:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-surround-40"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Surround 4.0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Surround 4.0"
        alsa.mixer_name = "IDT 92HD75B3X5"
        alsa.components = "HDA:111d7603,103c172b,00100202 HDA:11c11040,103c3066,00100200"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
    active port: <analog-output-speaker>
```

Notice the line ports on index 2 
analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
    active port: ”

I am guessing those are the laptop speacker but when trying:

```
pacmd set-card-profile 2 analog-output-speaker
```

I get:

```
No card found by this name or index.
```

[Here is a picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/opxhx1ycuz0m5n8/Screenshot%20from%202016-09-18%2002-57-23.png?dl=0) from the pulse audio contol.

etc etc…

My question is, how to know if is the hardware that broke?, because I try in Kali live usb drive and the sound doesn't work either so I thinking hardware its over!!.

---

So this is very very strange.Because i was unhappy with the idea of broken speackers i  reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 from scracth, erase the hole disk to find the same problem but still i was not happy so i went ahead and install windows 7 in a 30GB partition and guess what "They work".. yes let me reapet for some reason speackers dont work on Linux but they do with Windows wich make me happy because they are not broke.
 So my best guess is that the best way to find out if speackers are broke is to install Windows and see if they still not work there as well.

In the other hand i have a brand new system install with no speackers sound sure a open an other question then?

Comment: Since the speaker didn't work in Kali too, most probably it's a hardware issue

Comment: I'm not trying to insult your intelligence here, but have you tried unplugging the headphones?

Comment: Lol Nick.. Yeah Anwar, i was hopping i was wrong/..thanks

Comment: @Anwar I have heard that Kali Linux has issues with sound so I wouldn't call that definitive...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Month of trying, MESSING UP AROUND, errasing the Os reinstalling it  and back to trying;I found the solution at my problem:I install alsa-tools and alsa-tools-gui in Synaptic,within few apps after the install there is one call  HDAjackRetask, in there I override both headphones options to "Not Conected" and "install the override bot"*(this makes it permanent, Restart and the Speackers Work! now. 
I dont undestand how this funtion works.. how it afects the headphones jacks or anything just posting how i FIX it!!!...